# what is the function of webpages:Enabled in MVC 3 web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just started a new MVC 3 project. Can anyone tell me what

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

in my web.config file does?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful to note what happens if this is set and you attempt to browse a .chstml file. You get the error "This type of page is not served." Spent hours on this one :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533605/iis-express-webmatrix-2-wont-serve-cshtml-files-in-webapi-project-vs10-winx/12535137#12535137

Answer (score 254, accepted):

`webPages:enabled` with value `false` prevents `.cshtml` or `.vbhtml` files in the `Views` folder from being directly accessible from a web browser.

Comment: Actually it prevents them from being access directly regardless of where they reside in the application. In the views folder, in the root, in a different folder... doesn't matter you get the same error. `The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden`

Comment: Isn't that what the "BlockViewHandler" configuration is for? What is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, running a Nancy project on Mono and this setting appeared via nuget.  So I wonder, is this an IIS thing, and MVC 3 thing, or which part of the stack actually consumes this setting?

Comment: I'm not allowed to see Views by default, but if i add this setting and set it to false, they are now parsed and attempted to be viewed.

Comment: WebPages:Enabled enables it whether the value is true or false, the default value is null.

Answer (score 29):

According to documentation it prevents .cshtml and .vbhtml files from being accessed directly (`www.myweb.com/views/home/index.cshtml` for example)

Comment: I've been searching, but can't find a reference where this is explained. What I'd specifically like to know is what is the effect of omitting `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="???">` entirely. Is the default `true` or `false`?

Comment: So I've dug into the source code and the default value is actually `null` - meaning that webpages are enabled if application contains any `*.cshtml` or `*.vbhtml` files. Checking for files can be either disabled by setting this value to `true` or `false`. You can see for yourself [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages.Deployment/WebPagesDeployment.cs).

Comment: According to which documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To allow Razor pages to be served, it's not enough to set `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />`. You also need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages package to `packages.config` using NuGet.