# IIS Express (WebMatrix 2) won't serve .cshtml files in WebAPI project (VS10/WinXP)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am trying to run a WebAPI project on WinXP through WebMatrix 2.  I'm getting this error when attempting to browse index.cshtml (in the root):

[image: notservederror]

***"This type of page is not served."***

I created a WebAPI project under the MVC4 project type in Visual Studio 2010, then set the project to run under IIS Express.

**What I've Tried:**

The .NET CLR settings in the VS-created WebMatrix site is .NET 4.0 (Integrated).

I've already tried playing with the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` setting in Web.config, no luck.

The error occurs in both the development server and IIS Express.

I have already rebooted.

***However,*** if I create a Site *through the WebMatrix2 UI,* it works.  Razor .cshtml files added to that site through WebMatrix render just fine.

**TIA!**

Comment: What's the error? There might be an image that I can't see (might be blocked?)

Comment: @SpaceBison Updated the question with the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111625/iis-express-fails-to-serve-cshtml-files - could be same issue as this with previous version of webmatrix

Comment: @SpaceBison Thanks, I've been up and down that question, it doesn't help me.  The OP is using Win7, I'm on WinXP.

Comment: Is there an applicationHost.config for IISExpress running under WebMatrix? IsapiModule definitions in my own dev applicationHost.config (running under VS2010) point cshtm/cshtml/vbhtm/vbhtml to System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, perhaps it's the default behaviour? You no doubt already have been over all this....

Comment: @SpaceBison thanks for the applicationHost suggestion, it led me to the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**SUCCESS!**

The problem was a single line in the default WebAPI template web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />  <-- BAD!!!!
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Setting that `webpages:Enabled` setting to `true` fixed the problem and now my .cshtml files work.  Hope this helps others.

This question explains the `webpages:Enabled` setting: 
[what is the function of webpages:Enabled in MVC 3 web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886095/what-is-the-function-of-webpagesenabled-in-mvc-3-web-config)

Comment: cshtml files are not meant to be viewed directly.  They should be returned through the controller action (e.g. http://localhost:6068/People/Index)

Comment: @Peter that is true for MVC projects, but not for non-MVC projects using Razor syntax.  I'm learning to build a Single Page Application.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback - then you have exactly the correct solution

Comment: Good spot as this is a tricky one to troubleshoot.  Razor pages stopped working after I copied some files from an MVC project to a WebForms project. I removed the "BAD!" setting and was going again. Up Vote.