# web.config <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" /> makes custom membership provider not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

Can someone explain why when I have this in my web.config:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

I get this error pointing at my custom membership provider:

```
The pre-application start initialization method Start on type 
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode
```

Also, I never added that entry to my web.config; Visual Studio must have done it for me when I added .cshtml file to my web form project.  Supposedly that entry tells asp.net not to render .cshtml files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886095/what-is-the-function-of-webpagesenabled-in-mvc-3-web-config

Comment: I read/understand the explanation given in that thread, it doesn't answer my question though...

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when you add a razor page to an existing ASP.NET Project.
Just remove the line and it will work fine again :)

Answer (score 0):

This line also caused my LoginUrl to fall back to it's original value "/Account/Login" instead of taking a value from FormsAuthentication settings.

(Just in case anyone has the same problem)