# Server Error in '/' Application. This type of page is not served

Tags: asp.net, razor, web-config

I have an host where I hosted a webpage with `.cshtml` extension. My host is *arvixe.com* that provides ASP and .NET hosting but when I try to load my web page I get this error message.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This type of page is not served.
>
> Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /samples/WoT/Default.cshtml
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET  Version:4.0.30319.276

I read something does I have to write something in my web.config file to make it work
like this

```
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

But I tried everything, paste it in on different lines, nothing worked. What do I miss or do wrong?

Comment: is ASP.Net MVC installed properly?

Comment: Does it run on your dev machine?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I have the same problem, when running a default MVC 4 site on my dev machine.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are not making using the MVC feature and trying to load just the razor view outside views or custom Area folders.

Then you need to enable webpages key in Web.config which is disabled by default in .Net 4.0

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: look this for security   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886095/what-is-the-function-of-webpagesenabled-in-mvc-3-web-config

Answer (score 2):

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Repairing this in Windows 10 Pro using IIS 10 was a nightmare, it took two days but I was finally able to achieve the desired results using the following procedure:

1. Open your web site in Visual Studio. The way you do this is to go to **File > New > Web Site** and then select **ASP.Net Empty Web Site** AND before you click OK change the location to your project location. In my case I had my project in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNet\Projects\Test`
2. Open internet information services manager (click the "cortana" search and type IIS, it should show up as long as you have it installed). Locate your project folder under the **ServerName  > Sites > Default Web Site > ...** , right click on it and click the **"Convert to web Application"** button. Accepting the defaults at the prompt by clicking **OK** should be sufficient in most cases.
3. Use the following Web.Config file, or something similar. NuGet may overwrite some settings but this isn't a big problem.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Version" value="3.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

4. Delete your **bin** folder, and **packages.config** file, if they exist. This is because we must assume that something in that bin folder is corrupt since IIS is designed to run Razor/ASP. In your visual studio project you will need to refresh your project so it knows these files have been deleted. This can be done by clicking the refresh button in the menu on the top of the *Solution Explorer* frame. In you visual studio project go to **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console** and enter the following two commands.

   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -Version 3.0.0

   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

This was enough to get *.cshtml pages to be rendered by IIS 10 on Windows 10 Pro.