# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to learn some things with a source code but when I try to replicate myself this code I am getting that error.

I have a View *Index* where I am trying to access some .cshtml Templates from another folder.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div ng-controller="inboxIndexCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a ng-href="#/" id="InboxSubNav">Inbox</a>
            <hr />
            <a ng-href="#/sent" id="InboxSubNav">Sent</a>
            <hr />
            <a ng-href="#/create" id="InboxSubNav">Create</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11">

            <div class="well" ng-view></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var mail = angular.module('mail', ['ngRoute']);

mail.config([
    '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/Incoming.cshtml'
        })
            // Registering path with controller relative to Inbox/Index
            // This part is similar to RouteConfig.cs in ASP MVC
            .when('/message/:id', {
                // Templates are located inside Inbox.
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Message.cshtml',
                controller: 'oneMessageCtrl'
            }).when('/create', {
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Create.cshtml',
                controller: 'createCtrl'
            }).when('/reply/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Reply.cshtml',
                controller: 'replyCtrl'
            }).when('/sent', {
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Sent.cshtml',
                controller: 'sentCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    }
]);
```

_Layout have included ng-app`<html ng-app="mail">`. Also Angular bundle is loaded before Jquery, and this is done with localhost.

Versions I am using:

```
Angular 1.3.0-beta4
jquery-1.10.2
```

When the page loads, for a second it loads the `<div class="well" ng-view></div>` then dissapear.

When I hover the mouse above the links the path seems to be fine. When I click on links it goes on path but doesn't load anything due to 403 error.

Here some the links:

```
http://localhost:49602/Messages/Index#/
http://localhost:49602/Messages/Index#/sent
http://localhost:49602/Messages/Index#/create
```

My guess is that I am not using the right versions of Angular/Jquery or am I missing some packages?

Tried to View in browser one Template and got another error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       This type of page is not served.
>
> Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may
>   be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Messages/Templates/Create.cshtml

Comment: can you try

 >> http://localhost:49602/Messages/#/
 >> http://localhost:49602/Messages/#/sent
 >> http://localhost:49602/Messages/#/create

Comment: well I get this: `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.`

Comment: Also I have added this `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well with the help from stackoverflow I solved the problem:

Here is the solution: [Server Error in '/' Application. This type of page is not served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086595/server-error-in-application-this-type-of-page-is-not-served][1])

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

It was set on false in my webconfig

Comment: Thanks now I get this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`