# What is the effect of omitting "webpages:Enabled" in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've seen the question ["what is the function of webpages:Enabled in MVC 3 web.config"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886095/what-is-the-function-of-webpagesenabled-in-mvc-3-web-config) but the answer merely explains that setting it to "false" disables use of CSHTML pages (although the is no link to the documentation).

I have a project which fails to build unless the line `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true">` is removed from the web.config file.

Can someone (provide a link to) tell me what the effect of omitting it is? Is the default to allow or deny CSHTML pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default value is null which is interpreted as 'true' that would enable *.cshtml pages to be accessible directly.
You may refer to the code base here for reference:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages.Deployment/WebPagesDeployment.cs